# Recursive decryption using gpgdir

Tags: encryption, recursion, gnupg

I have a lot of files that are encrypted with gpg in a lot of directories. So I want to use `gpgdir` command to decrypt recursively all files in all directories.

The problem is in the use of gpgdir. I installed it correctly and I set the correct defualt key id in my conf file using `gpg --list-keys` to find the id. But when I use the command

```
gpgdir -decrypt <directory>
```

the console gives me back

```
[+] Executing: gpgdir -decrypt <directory>
    Using GnuPG key: 3662FD5E
Password:
```

I don't know what password I must insert to decrypt the files. I tried with the admin password but doesn't work.

Someone can help me?

Thanks!!

Comment: Presumably it want the password for the encrypted private key

Comment: But the private key is a simple file .private with the key without password. If I use the single command gpg on one file I haven't problems and passwords!

Comment: The private key `3662FD5E` is symmetrically encrypted with a passphrase, which you're asked for. If it isn't, try the empty passphrase.